# Custom index of Kentico searching in media library is not adding the index to the search

Tags: search, indexing, kentico, media-library

I'm trying to add a custom index for searching but the file is not added to the results. 
This is my code for rebuild method, is finding docs in the right media library but those are not being retrieved in results.

```
try
                {
                    MediaLibraryInfo library = MediaLibraryInfoProvider.GetMediaLibraryInfo("Documents", SiteContext.CurrentSiteName);

                    if (library != null)
                    {

                        var mediaFiles = MediaFileInfoProvider.GetMediaFiles().WhereEquals("FileLibraryID", library.LibraryID);// all files extension

                        List<string> files = new List<string>();

                        foreach (MediaFileInfo mediafile in mediaFiles)
                        {

                            SearchDocumentParameters documentParameters = new SearchDocumentParameters()
                            {
                                Index = srchInfo,
                                Type = SearchHelper.CUSTOM_SEARCH_INDEX,
                                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                                Created = mediafile.FileCreatedWhen
                            };
                            ILuceneSearchDocument doc = LuceneSearchDocumentHelper.ToLuceneSearchDocument(SearchHelper.CreateDocument(documentParameters));
                            doc.AddGeneralField(SearchFieldsConstants.CUSTOM_TITLE, mediafile.FileTitle, true, true);
                            doc.AddGeneralField("NAME", mediafile.FileName, true, true);
                            doc.AddGeneralField("DESCRIPTION", mediafile.FileDescription, true, true);

                            iw.AddDocument(doc);

                        }

                        iw.Flush();
                        iw.Optimize();
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    EventLogProvider.LogException("CustomTextFileIndex", "Rebuild", ex);
                }

                // Always close the index writer
                finally
                {
                    iw.Close();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines for doc.AddGeneralField with custom NAME and DESCRIPTION won't work with Kentico's default naming convention for columns, you should use the following instead:

```
doc.AddGeneralField(SearchFieldsConstants.CUSTOM_TITLE, mediafile.FileName, true, true);
doc.AddGeneralField(SearchFieldsConstants.CUSTOM_CONTENT, mediafile.FileDescription, true, true);
```

The default search mechanisms in Kentico won't use any custom column names for their queries. You'd have to create custom Lucene queries for that functionality. If you're already using CUSTOM_TITLE or CUSTOM_CONTENT fields for something else, then simply add the content to that same field, for example:

```
doc.AddGeneralField(SearchFieldsConstants.CUSTOM_TITLE, $"{mediafile.FileTitle} {mediafile.FileName}", true, true);
```

You can verify the Lucene index has included the records using a tool called Luke, I use version 3.5 (4+ won't work on the Kentico indexes)
https://code.google.com/archive/p/luke/downloads